# How do I use the time and date format specified in the Android settings?

Tags: android, date, time, settings

I would like to use the date and time formats specified in the Android's "Date & Time" settings. Is there an easy way to access this? I looked into the Settings class, however there is no constant that seems to have anything to do with these settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the specific Format instances that the user specified by using the [android.text.format.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) class. With those you just do your normal Java style date formatting.

Unfortunately there's no date AND time Format, so you're going to have to build it by yourself. Or you can use `DateUtils.formatDateTime()`, as Steve pointed out.

Comment: @Chris, are you just downvoting every answer that isn't yours? Lame.

Comment: @Steve, I know, we can play that game too though ;) And it's at least two of us.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! DateFormat has some nice methods to get the formats specified in the android settings, including getDateFormat() and getTimeFormat(). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, cal.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME); It allows you to display date AND time

Comment: DateUtils is now a depreciated class. Use SimpleDateFormat class. Example: SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMM d HH:mm a", Locale.getDefault());     String formattedDateTime = date.format( dateOrCalendarObject.getTime() );    would display "Tuesday, Apr 9 12:15 PM" assuming the dateOrCalendarObject's value was equal to that time.

Comment: Why do you say the class is deprecated? A bunch of the methods and constants are, but the class itself is still not _officially_ deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Comment: @Hrk This works for the main locale(ex: en_US or en_CA), but if you change to a custom date format under Date & time => Select date format, this won't reflect to what you selected.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateUtils.formatDateTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatDateTime%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20int%29)

Comment: The link to the sample app was not from me. It was a different user and was deleted.

Comment: As to whether it is helpful or not, perhaps that should be left up to the person asking the question? The answer was on topic and provides valuable information that your later answer doesn't provide.

Comment: What info doesn't it provide?  It uses the phone's locale to format a Date object into a String which is exactly what the user was looking form.

Comment: Your answer doesn't mention the `DateUtils.formatDateTime()` method. I didn't downvote your answer because you didn't mention that, I recommend you not downvote other answers just because you think your answer is better. Also, good job editing your previous comments to make you seem like less of a jerk.

Comment: I downvote 1 line answers that don't provide any real help and reserve the right to vote back up when there's an actual answer.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a way to it that's probably more distilled than scanning through applicable bits in an entire example app.  This is from my code where I need a locale-formatted date string without the ERA field:

```
final Date d = new Date();                

DateFormat dateFormat = null;
try {
    dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, <context>.getApplication().getLocale());
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL); // Default locale?  Users reported NPEs in the above checked code.
}
StringBuffer formattedDateBuf = new StringBuffer();
FieldPosition eraPos = new FieldPosition(DateFormat.ERA_FIELD);        
StringBuffer formattedDate = dateFormat.format(d, formattedDateBuf, eraPos);
```

Comment: This doesn't use the settings specified by the user (other than the Locale), which is what Phil was asking for.